# LookUp from two data extension for coupon code and if code is not available claim code from different DE

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

Need to send an Email with coupon code. If a subscribe has received coupon code before send the same code or if did not receive code claim a new coupon code from other Data extension. The below ampscript I wrote which gives an error.

```
%%[SET @code=Lookup('Jan_Newsletter_USD','secret_word','SubscriberKey',_subscriberkey)

IF EMPTY(@code) THEN
SET @code=Lookup('Jan_Newsletter_CAD','secret_word','SubscriberKey',_subscriberkey)

ELSE

SET @VoucherRow = ClaimRow('Feb_Newsletter_USD', 'IsClaimed','JobID', JobID, 'ListID', listid, 'BatchID', _JobSubscriberBatchID, 'SubscriberKey', _subscriberkey,'IncrementID', 1)

ELSEIF EMPTY(@VoucherRow) Then

 RaiseError('No valid voucher codes', true)

ELSIF

  SET @code = field(@VoucherRow,  'secret_word')

ENDIF
ENDIF]%%
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you mixed up the `if/else` statements. If you use indentation, it's easier to see where they start and end:

```
%%[
SET @code=Lookup('Jan_Newsletter_USD','secret_word','SubscriberKey',_subscriberkey)

IF EMPTY(@code) THEN
SET @code=Lookup('Jan_Newsletter_CAD','secret_word','SubscriberKey',_subscriberkey)

ELSE

SET @VoucherRow = ClaimRow('Feb_Newsletter_USD', 'IsClaimed','JobID', JobID, 'ListID', listid, 'BatchID', _JobSubscriberBatchID, 'SubscriberKey', _subscriberkey,'IncrementID', 1)

    IF EMPTY(@VoucherRow) Then

    RaiseError('No valid voucher codes', true)

    ELSE

    SET @code = field(@VoucherRow,  'secret_word')

    ENDIF

ENDIF
]%%
```

Comment: I accidentally downvoted your answer :-( Can you edit it, as I otherwise can’t retract my vote?

Comment: No worries ;-))